# How do I stop Messages from my iPhone 6s from appearing on my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, messages

How do I prevent messages from my iPhone 6s from appearing on my MacBook? I’ve tried everything obvious and various solution that haven’t worked.

My MacBook is running macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

On your MacBook, open **Messages**, then go into the menu bar Messages → Preferences → Accounts. Select your account labeled *iMessage*, and under **Settings**, either *uncheck* `Enable this account` or click `Sign Out`. You could also uncheck your phone number and every email address under **You can be reached for messages at**.

This will stop your Mac from being able to both send and receive iMessages. If you had **Text Message Forwarding** enabled for your Mac, this will stop it also.

Comment: Tried that.  No effect and I dont know why.  All I need do is open a conversation on my iphone and my Mac notifies me and opens messages.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @LaurenceKayson Under **You can be reached for messages at** have you tried unchecking your phone number and all email addresses?

Comment: What I've now done is to sign out from icloud on my iphone in settings, messages, send & receive, and that seems to have stopped it.  Your suggestion led the way.

Comment: Ha ha, but now I can't imessage from my iphone.  Giving up for a while, unless any ideas come my way

Comment: Okay I went into settings, general, hands off and that has worked.  Doesn't seem logical for that to be in General, but maybe that will bring it's own unintended consequences!  let's see.

Comment: This is a more general feature that allows you to continue whatever you’re doing on one device on another. **Messages** supports **Handoff**, but many other apps do a well.